# How to position components inside panelGrid for responsive layout

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

As shown in the screen-shot attached herewith I am trying to display an input text box and a search button both in the same row inside a 
panel in JSF.

I also want to make the content responsive with the screen size. The output **"What's the day today?"** is responsive to a great extent but both
the text box and the search button are not responsive.

Also the search button (and the input box) is huge quiet to my regret

Any help would be great.

**Code**

```
<h:head>
    <title>What's The Day Today</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <p:panel id="watsthedaytodayPanel"
            style="background: cyan; font-size: 50px; margin-left: 25%; margin-right:25%;margin-top:150px; text-align: center;">
            <p:outputLabel for="mycalendar" value="What's the day today ?" />
            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
            <p:inputText placeholder="Enter text..."
                    value="#{calendarView.day}"></p:inputText>
                <p:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{calendarView.search }"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" style="margin-left:20px;" update="result"></p:commandButton>
            <p:outputPanel id="result" ></p:outputPanel>

        </p:panel>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Original UI:**

[image]

**UI on Responsive 360*640 resolution as tested in Mozilla**

[image]

**Updated the Question With ScreenShot after the Font Size is fixed**

The font-size though fixed as mentioned in the comment the text box and search button is still not completely fluid with respect to the screen size as in the screenshot attached below. any  help would be thankful!
[image]

Comment: you yourself are responsible for making the font-size responsive...

Comment: @Kukeltje Aha Kukeltje ! We meet again! I am a relatively new to JSF and it's 0100 AM here in Bangalore. Can you please guide me how? At times I am thinking I should scamper back to my comfort "jQuery"zone. :-(

Comment: I went through the user guide Primefaces has and tried the CSS Grid option ui-g* but couldn't achieve the layout fluidity. Regretfully I couldn't put that piece of attempt here with my Q as I tried that in a different workstation.

Comment: @Kukeltje Hey, Kukeltje, my friend! I fixed the font issue as below:

<p:panel id="watsthedaytodayPanel"
   style="background: cyan; margin-left: 25%; margin-right:25%;margin-top:150px; text-align: center;">
   <h3>What's the day today ?</h3>
panel is a component element so everything inside was getting 50px size! Awwe! I know something about coding! Ha finally!

Comment: @Kukeltje The screen fluidity issue still remains for the input box and search button as updated in the latest screenshot in the updated Q. Any clue would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Again... ccs and media queries.. just make the inputtext smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve the below fluidity and responsiveness with the following changes made in my UI (**.xhtml file**).

**Code Change:** I made use of the grid option for the layout attribute in panelGrid and inside that used the div block with "ui-g" for a 12 column layout structure.

Disclaimer: This can be further optimized with the `<p:layout>` tag to achieve the perfect fluidity to any screen size. And I'll update the answer when I get time to do that.

```
<p:panelGrid id="mySearchPanel" columns="1" layout="grid">
        <p:panel id="watsthedaytodayPanel"
            style="background: cyan; margin-left: 25%; margin-right:25%;margin-top:150px; text-align: center;">
            <h1>What's the day today ?</h1>
                <div class="ui-g">
                        <p:inputText placeholder="Enter text here" style="margin-left:15%;margin-right:0.25%"
                            value="#{calendarView.day}" styleClass="ui-g-8"></p:inputText>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{calendarView.search}"
                            update="result" icon="ui-icon-search"></p:commandButton>
                </div>
                <p:outputPanel id="result" ></p:outputPanel>
        </p:panel>
        </p:panelGrid>
```

The screenshot of the UI:
[image: On a laptop/desktop]

[image: On a mobile screen Samsung 5]

Comment: I would **not** use `p:layout` for responsiveness... If you do not need the 'open and close' feature of the layout, you'd better use plain divs